# JavaScript, How to pre-populate a input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use some JavaScript for a checkbox. When a user makes the checkbox active there will be two fields displayed (This will be hidden soon).

This is the JavaScipt so far for the checkbox:

```
    <script>
        function myFunction(cbox) {
            if (cbox.checked) {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.id = cbox.name;
                div.innerHTML = "Text to display for " + cbox.name;
                div.appendChild(input);
                document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div);
            } else {
                document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

As you can see when the user clicks the box it will display an input box, however, I cannot seem to get that pre-populated. What I mean in this is, I was using an HTML tag before the javascript witch logged the users Identity.

```
        <input id="CheckedAndVerifiedBy" value="@User.Identity.Name" />
```

I would like the same thing to happen within the javascript, please help.

Comment: In your function `myFunction`, `input.value = whatever;` should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: `input.value` would be the way to go. But could you clarify what you want? Maybe we can give you a full solution then.

Comment: @Sens I am trying to create some code so when a user uploads a file some information gets logged such as there User Id and the time it was uploaded. I am also trying to make this hidden.

Comment: @M.E_ I would do that on serverside

Comment: @Sens Ok, Thanks, How do I go around this? Do you know any good guides?

Comment: @M.E_ Don't know any guides on that, sorry. It's just the way i would do it. Question also is, where do you get the User ID from, does he enter it himself?

Comment: @Sens No, This UserId is stored in the claims when the user is signed in, So I am grabbing it from there. I am doing this by using '@User.Identity.Name'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173760/discussion-between-sens-and-m-e).

Comment: So, this question was answered a couple of times here and on the internet. @M.E_ if you want you should post a new question with better detail (you want to log the user and time/date of the upload)
This thread should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input.value = "Prefilled!"
```

or something like that

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to give some value to the input before appending it.

Just do:

```
  ...
  input.type = "text";
  input.value = cbox.name;
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not in any moment assigning a value to `input`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('your_inpute_fied_id').setAttribute('value', 'the_value_you_wanna-set_to_it');
```